# MySQL Join vs Sub query vs?

Tags: mysql

Looking to avoid a potential problem here for future growth (think hundreds of thousands of records in a table)

I have two tables, one that houses documents and the other categories for these documents.  Essentially a document can have many categories.  I would like to be able to return all the corresponding categories for a document, sort of like so

doc.id, doc.name, .... , category1, category2

Figure there is two ways to achieve this

a) **Join** join the tables together using something like this then parse the output.  Issue here would be that we replicate the data for the document for as many categories as it belongs to

```
SELECT id, name, ..., category 
FROM doc
LEFT OUTER JOIN category ON (doc.id = category.docId)
```

b) **Sub Query** use a suq query to concatenate all the categories together.  Issue here is a potential performance issue

```
SELECT
  id, name, ....
  (SELECT group_concat(category,',') FROM category where category.docId = doc.id) as category
from doc
```

OR any other ideas that might work better, keeping performance in mind?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, use JOINs before subqueries. Google 'join fu jay pipes'.  He has some good presentations reinforcing this.

Comment: Personally, I find almost no use for either CONCAT or GROUP_CONCAT. I find the concatenation can be managed just as easily at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

create a view, which could be initially solution a) but it could be changed in the DB later to solution b) or c) if necessary.  This way no client code should need to change.